# Create a small very restricted software

Tags: embedded-systems

I'm looking for a software or a system that may do that :
- boot, ask for a password, then access to a screen
- having the ability to open an image (there is only one on the hard drive)
- opening images from usb sticks (plug in the usb, access list of files and open image)

nothing more ! Really nothing more, no copy, no paste, no access to other folders or capabilities, no sound, no internet, barely nothing !

The computer I have for doing this is over rated for the needs but the good thing is that it gives me more flexibility.

I've been thinking about embedded system or DOS based system, but I can't find anything.
Any Linux distrib I found let people copy files and make things like that and I could not find a way to disable it.
Even with openSUSE it gives too much abilities to user.

I'm kind of lost, and am aware of learning new codes or systems !

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Google for "kiosk mode"

Comment: That... Looks... Like... A very good beginning point !!!!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I would have written more, but was rushing to a meeting. Sometimes, though, all you need is the correct phrase. I am sure that you can take it from here :-)  Good luck

Comment: Well I think the best I found is CanBike OS, even though that little puppy icon is not very well for my needs :p

Comment: That's what we are here for ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found which is not perfect but worth trying and being investigated is to use CanBike OS in Kiosk mode.

You can have a web explorer (which I don't need), and when you plug in a USB stick then you can open it and check files. It's the only thing you can do !
The cons are that you can't customize anything, and you have the puppy icon on the menu (CanBike OS is based on Puppy OS).

You can find it there : http://www.canbike.org/off-topic/linux/can-bike-os-5-7-1-a-kiosk-edition.html

Comment: Hello everyone !
I finally made it another way...
I built an app on Unity that makes a fake OS which looks like a real one and that is SUPER limited ! If I want it on a computer I have to disable some keypad buttons, but I did this one on a tablet, and it works perfectly !!